# Select checkbox with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I need to check all values from this page; this page is reachable starting from:
https://unctadstat.unctad.org/wds/TableViewer/tableView.aspx
then selecting the icon "Select item to view" and then the value "YEAR":

[image]
:
[image]

I have to download all years by splitting in multiple files (say, ten years per file), so first, I unchecked all checkbox; then I have get all the labels of the years on the page, but now, I'm unable to select the associated checkbox:

```
const dataTemp = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // const ths = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#ItemsTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.DataItemSelections'));
    const ths = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#ItemsTable > tbody > tr > td.DataItemSelections'));

    return ths.map(value => value.innerHTML)
  });;
```

If I run:

```
const clickSelectors="#ItemsTable > tbody > tr > td > input[type=checkbox]";
await page.waitForSelector(clickSelectors);
await page.click(clickSelectors);
```

Only the first year (1970) is selected (I want to select all visible years).

Answer (score 1):

`waitForSelector` returns the result of a `document.querySelector` (not `document.querySelectorAll`) which returns the first items. After your `waitForSelector` you could do something like this:

```js
const els = await page.$$("#ItemsTable > tbody > tr > td > input[type=checkbox]");
const promises = els.map(e => e.click());
await Promise.all(promises);
```